# Duplicando menu bootstrap

Tags: php, css, html5, bootstrap, slimframework

Sou noob no desenvolvimento web e preciso de uma ajudinha dos colegas, se possível.

Estou fazendo um site, utilizando o bootstrap, e me deparei com um probleminha.
Tenho dois menus do tipo drop-down e quando clico em um ou em outro ambos os menus são abertos, conforme imagem abaixo:

PS: Utilizo o mesmo CSS para ambos os menus.

### [image: menu duplicado]

**HTML dos menus:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  <!-- Button Profile -->
  <div class="btn-cart-md">
      <a class="cart-link" href="#">
          <!-- Image -->
          <img class="img-responsive foto-redonda" src="/res/site/img/male.png" alt="" />

          <!-- Heading -->

              <h4>Olá, David Ferreira da Cunha</h4>
              <span>Minha conta</span>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>

              <ul class="cart-dropdown" role="menu">
                  <li>
                      <!-- Atralho para meus pedidos -->
                      <div class="cart-item">
                          <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#">Meus pedidos</a>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <!-- Atalho para configurações da conta -->
                      <div class="cart-item">
                          <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#">Configurações</a>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <!-- Atalho para finalizar sessão no navegador -->
                      <div class="cart-item">
                          <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" href="#">Sair</a>
                      </div>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>

      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
  <!-- Button Kart -->
  <div class="btn-cart-md">
      <a class="cart-link" href="#">
          <!-- Image -->
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/res/site/img/cart.png" alt="" />
          <!-- Heading -->
          <h4>Meu carrinho</h4>
          <span>0 itens 0,00</span>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </a>
      <ul class="cart-dropdown" role="menu">
          <li>
              <!-- Cart items for shopping list -->
              <div class="cart-item">
                  <!-- Item remove icon -->
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                  <!-- Image -->
                  <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="/res/site/img/nav-menu/nav1.jpg" alt="" />
                  <!-- Title for purchase item -->
                  <span class="cart-title"><a href="#">Exception Reins Evocative</a></span>
                  <!-- Cart item price -->
                  <span class="cart-price pull-right red">$200/-</span>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <!-- Cart items for shopping list -->
              <div class="cart-item">
                  <!-- Item remove icon -->
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                  <!-- Image -->
                  <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="/res/site/img/nav-menu/nav2.jpg" alt="" />
                  <!-- Title for purchase item -->
                  <span class="cart-title"><a href="#">Taut Mayoress Alias Appendicitis</a></span>
                  <!-- Cart item price -->
                  <span class="cart-price pull-right red">$190/-</span>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <!-- Cart items for shopping list -->
              <div class="cart-item">
                  <!-- Item remove icon -->
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                  <!-- Image -->
                  <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="/res/site/img/nav-menu/nav3.jpg" alt="" />
                  <!-- Title for purchase item -->
                  <span class="cart-title"><a href="#">Sinter et Molests Perfectionist</a></span>
                  <!-- Cart item price -->
                  <span class="cart-price pull-right red">$99/-</span>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <!-- Cart items for shopping list -->
              <div class="cart-item">
                  <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" href="#shoppingcart1">Resumo do pedido</a>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Alguém sabe me explicar o que estou fazendo de errado?
Quando o usuário clicar em um menu a página deverá abrir o drowp-down referente ao menu clicado e não os dois ao mesmo tempo.

**Abaixo o CSS.**

Como ele é muito grande e não cabe aqui na descrição da pergunta, segue o link para que vocês possam visualizar.

http://ashobiz.dreamhosters.com/wrapbootstrap/cakefactory145/css/style.css

Comment: Insira o CSS e jQuery/Javascript se houver para que se possa testar o seu código e ajudá-lo.

Comment: Olá @EliseuB. Como o CSS é muito grande estou enviando o link onde o mesmo se encontra. http://ashobiz.dreamhosters.com/wrapbootstrap/cakefactory145/css/style.css

Comment: É este layout que você está usando?
http://ashobiz.dreamhosters.com/wrapbootstrap/cakefactory145/

Testei no Chrome, Edge e no Firefox e funcionou normalmente. Se você puder disponibilizar a sua URL e ver os códigos adicionais que você fez, que possivelmente deu bug, poderia melhor te ajudar.

Comment: tente adicionar  o  codigo  fonte do navegador, sem  as  tags que vc utiliza no  seu  frame work

Comment: @EliseuB.é esse leiaute mesmo. A questão é que eu adicionei uma div ao lado do carrinho. Se você observar no leiaute do linlk que me enviou só tem a div do carrinho de compras. No meu localhost eu adicionei uma div do lado para o perfil de usuários (favor observar imagem que postei acima). Eu uso as mesmas classes para ambas as divs, quando clico em qualquer uma delas sempre abre os dois popups.

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons infelizmente o código na página ultrapassa o limite de caracteres. Tem alguma outra forma de postar ela?

Comment: coloca so a parte que está o  seu  menu deve estar  dentro do <container> ou  do  <nav> <header>

Comment: pois ai  consigo testar  aqui

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons atualizei a descrição da pergunta com o HTML da página, sem o PHP do framework. Serve para você?

Comment: Não tem um jQuery que abre os menus?

Comment: @ÐvÐ tem esse: $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.btn-cart-md .cart-link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $dd_menu = $('.btn-cart-md .cart-dropdown')
  if ($dd_menu.hasClass('open')) {
   $dd_menu.fadeOut();
   $dd_menu.removeClass('open');
  } else {
   $dd_menu.fadeIn();
   $dd_menu.addClass('open');
  }
 });
});

As duas divs estão usando. Seria esse o problema?

Comment: @ÐvÐ valeu brother! Era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme código informado nos comentários:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.btn-cart-md .cart-link').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var $dd_menu = $('.btn-cart-md .cart-dropdown');
      if ($dd_menu.hasClass('open')) {
         $dd_menu.fadeOut(); $dd_menu.removeClass('open');
      } else {
         $dd_menu.fadeIn(); $dd_menu.addClass('open');
      }
   });
});
```

**1.** Não é necessário incluir `.cart-link` no seletor. Basta `.btn-cart-md` que já engloba o link do botão.

**2.** Em `var $dd_menu = $('.btn-cart-md .cart-dropdown');`, é preciso especificar um único `<ul>` com a classe `.cart-dropdown` que será aberta, usando `.find`.

O código ficaria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.btn-cart-md').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var $dd_menu = $(this).find('.cart-dropdown');
      if ($dd_menu.hasClass('open')) {
         $dd_menu.fadeOut(); $dd_menu.removeClass('open');
         } else {
            $dd_menu.fadeIn(); $dd_menu.addClass('open');
      }
   });
});
```